# Transparent background overriding box-shadow

Tags: css

I'm trying to create the effect below with CSS, but i'm having problems with the transparent background. It's like the background didn't really got transparent and still overriding the box-shadow.

What i want:

[image]

What i have:

[image]

Here's my code

```
        .button {
            border-radius: 500px;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: transparent;
            border: 2px solid black;
            color: white;
            font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
            font-size: 250%;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px 100px;
            font-weight: 900;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px 0px rgba(140,122,230,1);
            -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px 0px rgba(140,122,230,1);
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px 0px rgba(140,122,230,1);
            -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
        }
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you faced here is with the `shadow` property. CSS shadows always appear behind the element and it's not going to see through the transparent background also. So here's a little trick that you can achieved the expecting behavior with CSS `position` property.

```css
.but-container{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
button{
    z-index:1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
    border-radius: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
    font-size: 250%;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 100px;
    font-weight: 900;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
}
.but-shadow{
    z-index: -1;
    top: 8%;
    left: 3%;
    border-radius: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(140,122,230,1);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="but-container">
  <button>GO</button>
  <div class="but-shadow"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see here you have to use an outer container which containing both the `<button>` and the `<div>` that act as the shadow. since the widths and heights of those elements are relative to the parent with percentage values, you can resize the outer `<div>` container size as you wish the inner elements will always will be the exact same size as the outer `<div>`. so it can use with a responsive designs also.